# How can I get Ninject to work in WIndows 8 metro style app

Tags: ninject, windows-8

Has anyone managed to get Ninject working in Metro Style app using the Windows 8 Developer preview?
If so how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running Ninject in Metro Style apps requires several changes in the implementation of Ninject. Therefore there is no way to run current builds in metro style apps. If you are willing to do the required chages to Ninject then you have to perform the following steps

1. Create a new MS library project
2. Add all files from Ninject
3. Define NO_LCG NO_ASSEMBLY_SCANNING NO_EXCEPTION_SERIALIZATION
4. Fix all the problems related to the chages to the new reflection API

Otherwise you have to wait until there is an official preview of Ninject for Metro Style Apps which will be available sometime after the Ninject 3.0 release.

Comment: An alternative is to rebuild Ninject using the .NET Portable Class Library tools [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx] - far fewer code changes will be required, especially if Ninject already has Silverlight or Phone build configurations. @Remo, let me know if you'd like more details on this approach (I'm on the team that designed both the portability tools and .NET reflection APIs).

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt I'm aware of Portable libraries and this is one thing I planned for a upcomming refactoring. But unfortunately not everything can be done unsing protable libraries. E.g assembly scanning. The plan is to have a portable core that is used by a platform specific assembly which adds everything that is not supported by portable libraries.

Comment: @Remo How's the Portable Class Library topic coming? any progress on that? Ninject's home page doesn't exactly have a news feed so I thought I'd ask ;)

Comment: @Maciek See https://github.com/onovotny/ninject/commit/21e25448968491f2a9f738a6f714844f06b5ea25 this will be reviewed and probably merged in the near future.

Comment: Any word on Windows 8 compatibility yet? This is the most definitive source of information thus far...I don't see any details about Windows 8 support on the Ninject site yet...however it would be wonderful to be able to do proper DI/IOC with Windows 8 apps.